# Setting hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES make app crash sometimes (uvSendEvents)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

Setting hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES  makes my app crash sometimes if user scroll up/down repeatedly. I have the report from Crashlytics but unable to reproduce it consistently.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Trying to finish an interactive transition that was not started interactively
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182154f5c    __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000196c5bf80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182154e2c +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x0000000183043f3c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKit                          0x0000000187f237fc -[_UIAnimationCoordinator finishInteractiveAnimation]
5  UIKit                          0x0000000187a38980 -[UINavigationController _gestureRecognizedInteractiveHide:]
6  UIKit                          0x0000000187c03b0c _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions
7_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions
8  UIKit                          0x00000001876dd690 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:]
9  UIKit                          0x0000000187c04e5c ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke809
10 UIKit                          0x000000018769d0fc _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks
11 UIKit                          0x000000018769b1d0 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate
12 UIKit                          0x00000001876db548 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:]
13 UIKit                          0x00000001876daaac -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
14 UIKit                          0x00000001876aba10 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
15 MyAppName                     0x0000000100486d78 uvSendEvents
16 UIKit                          0x00000001876a9efc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue
17 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018210c5a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
18 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018210c038 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
19 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182109d38 __CFRunLoopRun
20 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182038dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
21 GraphicsServices               0x000000018d18c088 GSEventRunModal
22 UIKit                          0x0000000187712f44 UIApplicationMain
23 MyAppName                     0x00000001000ea740 main (main.m:32)
24 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001974868b8 start
```

I found the same bug report in openradar but couldn't find a solution to this. 
https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/236
http://www.openradar.appspot.com/20000000

Please help

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a custom navigation bar? I had this same issue, and following the customisation pattern used in Apple's [NavBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html) example fixed the issue for me (I suspect it was implementing layoutSubviews and cleaning up the view hierarchy did the trick).

Comment: I have this issue as well, but I'm not using a custom navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The thing I was doing wrong was I had kept the navigationController's property -

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

**Plus**

I was managing navigation controller hide/unhide manually on scroll.

So the two transitions were overriding simultaneously.

Comment: so what was the solution?